# Does every large enough string have repeats?

Tags: combinatorics, strings, word-combinatorics

Let $\Sigma$ be some finite set of characters of fixed size. Let $\alpha$ be some string over $\Sigma$. We say that a nonempty substring $\beta$ of $\alpha$ is a *repeat* if $\beta = \gamma \gamma$ for some string $\gamma$.

Now, my question is whether the following holds:

> For every $\Sigma$, there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every string $\alpha$ over $\Sigma$ of length at least $n$, $\alpha$ contains at least one repeat.

I've checked this over the binary alphabet, and this is quite easy for that case, but an alphabet of size 3 is already quite a bit harder to check, amd I'd like a proof for arbitrarily large grammars.

If the above conjecture is true, then I can (almost) remove the demand for inserting empty strings [in my other question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/666/is-there-a-string-stack-data-structure-that-supports-these-string-operations).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, unfortunately not. There are even infinite [*square-free*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squarefree_word) words if your alphabet has at least three symbols.

This apparently natural border (two-element alphabets have only finitely many square-free words) is observed in many places, for instance:

- $\{xyyz \mid x,y,z\in \Sigma^+\}$ is co-finite for $|\Sigma|\leq 2$ but not context-free for $\Sigma>2$.
- The class of languages generated by terminal-free [patterns](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-0000%2880%2990041-0) can be [learned in the limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_learning_theory#Learning_in_the_limit) if $|\Sigma|>3$ but not so if $|\Sigma|=2$ [[Reid2004](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2005.10.017)].

Comment: Damn, that's too bad then :S