# Example of a superword w such that v^2 isn't its subword

Tags: formal-languages

What is an example of an infinite word(superword) w such that if a nonempty word v belongs to L = {1,2,3}*, v^2 isn't a subword of w?

For example if w = 123123123...123 and v = 123, v^2 = 123123 hence it's a subword of w, I can't seem to find a superword that fits the requirement.

Comment: I think 123111222333111112222233333... works? No?

Comment: at first we have one 1, one 2, one 3, then three 1's, three 2's and three 3's, then 5 of each, then 7 of each, then 9 of each, etc

Comment: But you have double letters - the word "1" repeats a lot as $1^2$ (same goes for 2 and 3)

Comment: oh yeah, you're right, hmm, seems impossible

Comment: [Related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/757/98).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a dedicated page on "square-free words" on wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word), with references. As you can see, there is an exemple of a square-free word on a three lettre alphabet.

Comment: For some reason, the [French version of this page](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot_sans_facteur_carré) gives even more examples.

Comment: Russian version too, and I am Russian