# Is the given language finite or infinite?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I have an idea regarding whether this language is finite or not, but for some reason I am still having some issues regarding exactly grasping what makes a language finite or infinite. I know that basically a language such as $0^*$ is obviously infinite since there can be any nonnegative number of $0$'s. However, is a language such as $(0 \cup 1)((0 \cup 1)^p)((0 \cup 1)^p)(0 \cup 1))$ also infinite? Technically, there can be any number of $0 \cup 1$ as it matters on the $p$ value, but I am also under the impression that there can only be so many values for $p$ and therefore the language is indeed finite. Can anyone explain as to why the language is either finite or infinite? I have read other examples but get a little confused when the language is in the gray area. Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to [CS.SE]. The lack of helpful formatting makes your post hard to comprehend. Please take some time to improve the presentation (add some space and split to paragraphs; use Latex if possible for mathematical expressions); we collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/820/). Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm basically just looking at a Pushdown Automata and roughly translating it into a regular expression. Given the PDA, I am under the assumption that p has to be greater than or equal to 0, but that is the only condition I have. Therefore, is it safe to say that the language is infinite? Even though both the second and third term require the same value for p?

Comment: It looks like you might have inadvertently created two accounts.  I recommend you merge your accounts; please see http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts for details.  Also, I suggest you create an account and register it, to ensure you retain access: see http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/why-register.

Comment: I don't see the relation to PDAs. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 4):

`(0 U 1)((0 U 1)^p)((0 U 1)^p)(0U1))`  is not a language, but a regular expression. Moreover, to be well-defined, you must specify what $p$ is.

Is $p$ a specific value?  Then, this expression generates a finite number of words -> it generates a finite language.

But maybe you look at the language generated by the above expression for **any** p? then, there will be infinitely many generated words.

**you** need to tell us what is $p$ and what is the language under consideration.

Answer (score 0):

> what makes a language finite or infinite

That's pretty clear by definition. In general, it's (algorithmically) impossible to tell from some description. There are also examples that are [deliberately obscure](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/758/98) so students have to think.

> as it matters on the p value

Exactly. Regular expressions do, syntactically, not allow for integer variables. So you have to consider a fixed (if arbitrary) value for p.

> when the language is in the gray area

There is no gray area; the question you ask is ill-posed is all. What is the *exact* definition of the language?